# Unarchiving data returning null values

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, nsuserdefaults, nskeyedunarchiver

I have created an app which is based off a previous app. I am trying to move the data over. I am using swift currently and the previous app is using object c. I am using this global object C function which is essentially copied over from the other app. It is able to grab the data and the message count is correct, but when I go to look up a value it returns null. See Below.

```
NSUserDefaults *prefs;
prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

NSMutableArray *oldMessages = [prefs objectForKey:@"savedMessages"];

//received
if(oldMessages)
{
    for( NSData *data in oldMessages )
    {
        NSKeyedUnarchiver *customUnarchiver = [[NSKeyedUnarchiver alloc] initForReadingWithData:data];
        [customUnarchiver setClass:[myMessage class] forClassName:@"Message"];
        myMessage* message = [customUnarchiver decodeObjectForKey:@"root"];
        [customUnarchiver finishDecoding];

        NSLog(@"message!!!%@", message.messageBody); // returns null, but in previous app it returns a value.
    }
}

return oldMessages;
```

Comment: Is `-initWithCoder:` if your class `myMessage` called and returns a non-nil value?

Comment: it returns "self" this is also copied directly from the previous app

Comment: Anyway you should validate and check whether initializer is called or not. Also `self` could already be `nil` there. - And you should set `NSKeyedUnarchiver`'s `delegate` (`cannotDecodeObjectOfClassName` method) which could give another hint why the decoding doesn't work.

Comment: ok, Thanks. That points me in the right direction at least. I will check

Comment: It turns out I accidentally commented it out one line in the decoder. I thought this would have ether returned an error or just not returned a value for that specific value.